# Having both Windows 10 and Windows 7 - chkdsk

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, multi-boot, chkdsk

I have windows 7 on a 3TB HDD and windows 10 on a 250GB SSD (windows 10 is installed after 7). One day after going from 10 to 7, it ran CHKDSK on my system and a lot of security IDs changed and my windows 7 didn't boot up and I forced to reinstall it. After that I found that it is caused by **Fast startup** and **I disabled it**. But even with this, sometime after using windows 10 and going to windows 7, A CHKDSK is run on my computer. these CHKDSKs didn't lead to serious problem and no security IDs changed.  But I am nervous about that and didn't use Win10 since then.

I want to know what other things I must do so I can be sure about that No CHKDSK will run?

My main OS is windows 7 and I do most of my works with windows 7 because I think for my works, it is more comfortable than Win10 (In my opinion).  I just use Win10 for some softwares and games which are windows store exclusives and are not available on Win7. So my priority is using both of them not using just Win10 or Win7.

Comment: Chkdsk will run automatically if there is file system corruption, nothing you can do to prevent it.

Comment: @Moab I know when chkdsk runs. my problem is that every 2 or 3 times I go from win10 to win7 it runs. I want to know why it happens. there must be something causing it.